# How do I make the apps/widgets view the default view?

Tags: launcher, app-drawer

I just got my first Android device (a tablet). I noticed there's two views. One with a wallpaper and some apps, and another view similar to Launchpad on the Mac (shown below):

[image: screen shot]

I want to get rid of the view with the wallpaper in it and just have the "launchpad" view as my default. Is that possible?

Comment: That's called the "App Drawer", by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install a custom Launcher.

A launcher is the application that you use to launch other applications. It is both the home screen (view with wallpaper) and launcher draw ("launchpad").

With Android you can install different launchers via the Play Store to suit your own needs.

For example [AppDrawer (MIUI App Drawer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=JakedUp.AppDrawer) might be what you're looking for.